# Characters of semidirect and wreath products of non-Abelian finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product, wreath-product

In Section 3.2 of [Linear Representations of Finite Groups](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4684-9458-7) by Serre, the author gives a formula to compute the characters of product of finite groups (Abelian or non-Abelian).

First Serre defines the product of two groups.

> Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two groups, and let $G_1 \times G_2$ be their
>   product, that is, the set of pairs $\left(s_1, s_2\right)$, with $s_1
>  \in G_1$ and $s_2 \in G_2$. Then,
>
> $$ \left(s_1, s_2\right) \cdot \left(t_1, t_2\right) = \left(s_1 t_1,
>  s_2 t_2\right) $$

Then, Serre introduced the representation of the product as follows.

> Now let $\rho^1 : G_1 \to GL\left(V_1\right)$ and $\rho^2 : G_2 \to
>  GL\left(V_2\right)$ be linear representations of $G_1$  and $G_2$
>   respectively. We define a linear representation $\rho^1 \otimes rho^2$
>   of $G_1 \times G_2$ into $V_1 \otimes V_2$ by setting
>
> $$\left(\rho^1 \otimes \rho^2\right)\left(s_1, s_2\right) = \rho^1
>  \left(s_1\right) \otimes \rho^2 \left(s_2\right)$$

Finally, comes the formula for computing the characters of the product.

> $$\chi \left(s_1, s_2\right) =  \chi_1 \left(s_1\right) \cdot \chi_2
>  \left(s_2\right)$$

In the same section, Serre introduces **Theorem 10** which is as follows.

> Theorem 10: (i) If $\rho^1$ and $\rho^2$ are irreducible, $\rho^1
>  \otimes \rho^2$ is an irreducible representation of $G_1 \times G_2$.
>
> (ii) Each irreducible representation of $G_1 \times G_2$ is isomorphic
>   to a representation $\rho^1 \otimes \rho^2$, where $rho^i$ is an
>   irreducible representation of $G_i (i = 1, 2)$.

**My question:**
Do we have similar results for semidirect and wreath products of non-Abelian finite groups?

**My effort:**
I have found in Section 8.2 of Serre how to compute the characters when one of the group is Abelian. I have no clue how to extend the idea for non-Abelian group. In [Representations of semidirect products](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/representations-of-semidirect-products/), Akhil Mathew defines the irreps of semidirect products but it is not clear to me how to compute the character of the product.

Comment: Omar I was looking for the same thing while back and I didn't find something concrete unfortunately. At Etingof's Introduction to representation theory there is a section for representations of semidirect products. Though isn't something fancy.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris, let me check the reference you mentioned.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris, did you check this (http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-13/2/281.extract)?